# How can I estimate the clarity of a color?

Tags: algorithm, math, colors, shader

This question might sound a little bit broad, but how can I estimate the clarity of a rgb color?

I'm trying to create a function f(rgb) that returns 0 if the rgb is black (0,0,0), 1 if it is white (1,1,1) and something in between for other rgb colors.

---

What I'm trying is this:

**f(rgb) = min(rgb) + c<sub>1</sub>r +  c<sub>2</sub>g + c<sub>3</sub>b**

First I take the minimum value of the rgb channels, then I add it with the products between each channel and a predefined constant.

```
Example: rgb = (0.4, 0.8, 0.5)
f(rgb) = min(0.4, 0.8, 0.5) + 0.4 c1 + 0.8 c2 + 0.5 c3
f(rgb) = 0.4 + 0.4 c1 + 0.8 c2 + 0.5 c3
```

But obviously I don't know the values of the constants, I would have to test them manually.

This is why I'm asking if there is a way already.

Comment: What do you mean by 'clarity'? That is not a prescribed value of the color property. So yes... you _would_ have to test each one manually, since you're inventing the metric you want to test. Also, this probably depends on the language that is implementing the color you want to test, not to mention the language you want to use to implement this. I think this question needs more clarity... pun intended.

Comment: The answer already explains what I mean. The question is clear, I want to see how bright a color is. "I'm trying to create a function f(rgb) that returns 0 if the rgb is black (0,0,0), 1 if it is white (1,1,1) and something in between for other rgb colors". Also the question has nothing to do with a specific programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got an idea: convert the color to grayscale.

[Here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2gray.html) I could find an algorithm that does that:

> f(rgb) = 0.299r + 0.587g + 0.114b